# How to turn a PHP sitemap into a XML one

Tags: php, xml, dynamic, sitemap

I came up with a PHP version of a sitemap file for my dynamic site which only has index.php. Here is the result: http://www.oddsnavigator.eu/sitemap.php

Now I need a way to either export those results to sitemap.xml file, or to make this one XML and Google-friendly. Here's the code:

```
<?PHP
$SQL="boring query";
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($SQL));
echo $num_rows , "</BR>";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
if($result === FALSE) { die(mysql_error());}

while($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$goto = "http://oddsnavigator.eu/?display=0&sport=" . $db_field['sportid'] . "&day=all&league=" . $db_field['stageid'];
$title = $db_field['sportname'] . " " . $db_field['tempname'] . " " . $db_field['stagename'] . " Sports Betting Odds Comparison - OddsNavigator.eu";

echo "<a href='$goto' title='$title'>" , $db_field['sportname'] , " " , $db_field['tempname'] , " " , $db_field['stagename'] , "</a>" , "</BR>";
}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your code `$goto` contains URLs, store all these url in an array called $urls and then use following function.
I expect the code goes in `class`, if not replace `$this->variable` with `$variable`.

```
//$urls = array();
$compress = true;

function save () 
{
    if (empty($this->urls)) return;
    $file = "sitemap.xml{$this->compress}";
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n";
    $xml .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">' . "\n";
    foreach ($this->urls as $url) 
    {
        $xml .= '  <url>' . "\n";
        if (is_array($url)) {
            foreach ($url as $key => $value) $xml .= "    <{$key}>{$value}</{$key}>\n";
        } 
        else {
            $xml .= "    <loc>{$url}</loc>\n";
        }
        $xml .= '  </url>' . "\n";
    }
    $xml .= '</urlset>' . "\n";
    $this->urls = array();
    if (!empty($this->compress)) $xml = gzencode($xml, 9);
    $fp = fopen(BASE_URI . $file, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, $xml);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Sounds good! But how exactly do I store the $goto values as an array?

Comment: Replace `$goto = "http://oddsnavigator.eu/?display=0&sport=" . $db_field['sportid'] . "&day=all&league=" . $db_field['stageid'];` with `$this->urls[] = "http://oddsnavigator.eu/?display=0&sport=" . $db_field['sportid'] . "&day=all&league=" . $db_field['stageid'];`

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/oddsnavi/public_html/sitemap.php on line 35. (the line starting with $this...)

Comment: I got it to store the results in an array $urls by replacing $this->urls with $urls. But the bottom part of the code, where results are saved in sitemap.xml, doesn't seem to work as the file is not being created.

Comment: Your code had errors but you guided me towards the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @DanHorvat Can you please point out the errors, so that i can correct the listed code

Comment: I will post the entire code as an answer in 4 hours (not allowed to now because of low reputation). I deleted the function save part as it's not necessary. The $xml . = urlset line contains ' " " ' instead of " ' ' ". The if-then loops are unnecessary as it's a straightforward operation. I removed the $file variable and used straight 'sitemap.xml' code in $fp. And last but not least, all '?' and '&' signs must be replaced by entity codes, &#63; and &amp; respectively, and the url must have an / at the end. I am not sure which part of your code didn't work but with these changes - it works.

Comment: Actually, I clearly remember the first time sitemap.xml was actually created happened when I removed the $file variable and replaced it with outright 'sitemap.xml' in $fp. And then nothing was written to the file so I removed all redundant things. And finally, the sitemap wasn't validated by Google until I used entity codes. All is well that ends well. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey sorry man, I posted wrong value for `$compress` it should go like `$compress = '.gz'`. This is used to get gz compressed sitemap files. still you nicely figured it out, thanks for the reply...

Answer (score 1):

And here's the full code of the solution, for future reference if anyone is having the same problem. The code uses SQL query to extract information from the database and then passes is on into a XML file.

```
<?PHP

$SQL="boring query";

$result = mysql_query($SQL);

//assigning the value of the URL which will be moved to sitemap.xml
while($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$urls[] = "http://oddsnavigator.eu/?display=0&sport=" . $db_field['sportid'] . "&day=all&league=" . $db_field['stageid'];
}

mysql_close($db_handle);

$compress = true;
//setting the sitemap.xml header
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" . "\n";
$xml .= "<urlset xmlns='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'>" . "\n";

//adding each element
foreach ($urls as $url) 
{
$xml .= '  <url>' . "\n";
if (is_array($url)) {
foreach ($url as $key => $value) $xml .= "    <{$key}>{$value}</{$key}>\n";
} 
else {
$xml .= "    <loc>{$url}</loc>\n";
$xml .= "    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>\n";
}
$xml .= '  </url>' . "\n";
}
$xml .= '</urlset>' . "\n";
$urls = array();

//writing to file
$fp = fopen('sitemap.xml', 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $xml);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template engine such as Smarty.

That would allow you to easily loop through the creation of the XML.

Or you could use [http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php SimpleXML].

If you already use a template engine, that would probably be the quickest and easiest solution. Otherwise, I would use SimpleXML.

Comment: I'm looking to do it something like this: http://www.seopher.com/articles/writing_a_php_google_sitemap_generator_without_using_fopen